# PHP encoded with Zend Guard and composer

Tags: php, composer-php, zend-loader

My `composer.json` file contains

```
{
...
"autoload":{
"classmap":["src/"]
}
...
}
```

`src/` contains encoded PHP files.

But when I try to run `php composer.phar update --no-dev` it generates the `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` file without any mapping.

There are solution actually - to make update vendors with Composer before encode them, but this is has no-sense and every time when somebody updates Composer autoloader, I need to encode all project again.

Comment: You could provide your own autoloader ...

Comment: Hi, I have similar case to you, did you find any solution rather than copying the auto-load files?